# Editing watermarks from docx documents in libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice

I got a word docx document from an MSoffice user which has a "Draft" mark as a water mark for pages. This appears as an object in Libreoffice named "PowerPlusWaterMarkObjectxxxx".
Is there any simple way to edit it (I mean change the text)? Do I need any kind of plugin there?

Answer (score 1):

Open the Navigator (from the View menu, or by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>).

The last item in the list should be Draw Objects. Expand this by clicking the little arrow on its left.

Select and delete one by one all watermarks (in case there are multiple ones).

<sub>Source: [AskLibreoffice - Turning off Draft watermark?](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/6928/turning-off-draft-watermark/)</sub>

Comment: You have suggested the way to delete the watermark. Please suggest how to edit as asked in question.